# Javascript code behaving differently based only on the presence of a couple of alert statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) to do a product lookup. I am using the following code to enforce selection from a list:

```
$(".force-selection").blur(function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  //check if the input's value matches the selected item
  alert($(this).val());
  alert($(this).data('selected-item'));
  if(value != $(this).data('selected-item')) {
    //they don't, the user must have typed something else
    $(this)
      .val('') //clear the input's text
      .data('selected-item', ''); //clear the selected item
  }
});
```

The above code ONLY works when the two alert statements are removed. Why would the behavior change based only upon the presence of a couple of alert statements?

Comment: Race conditions? Perhaps there is something else firing while alert box is being displayed?

Comment: you should handle the autocomplete's [change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change) event, not the input box `blur` event.

Comment: The autocomplete lookup is asynchronous. You will have to wait for that, and the alerts propably halt your code long enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching to use the [Autocomplete change event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-change) instead of the blur event.

- Either as an `init` option when creating the Autocomplete:

  ```
  $(".selector").autocomplete({
     change: function(event, ui) { ... }
  });
  ```
- Or bind to the change event by type: autocompletechange.

  ```
  $(".selector").bind("autocompletechange", function(event, ui) {
     ...
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by several issues.

If you're using Internet Explorer, the `alert` will cause the 'blur' event to fire on whatever field you're working in. In your sample code, it's obvious why that will cause issues. Otherwise, you're probably looking at a race condition issue.

Check out this fiddle in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/NsfKT/